# Better way to create samples

Tags: java, algorithms, recursion, sample

I've done this piece of code for creating bernulli samples, but I think that it is a so heavy algorithm because every time I call this recursive function I create a new vector that is passed to it. Is there a way for making this algorithm faster?

Here is the algorithm and the description:

As already said, this function creates bernulli samples recursively. If `n`, that is the number of elements that should be found, is equals 0 I print the sample.

Else to the sample that is passed I add every element of the population (I have to create a vector for everyone of this new samples), and I call the function with this new sample and n(the number of element to be found) decremented.

```
private static void distribuzioneBernoulli(int n, Vector<Float> population, Vector<Float> sample){
    // exit condition, when n equals 0 the fuction doesn't self-calls
    if(n==0){
        JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialog(null, campione);
    }

    // Every element of the population is added to the sample,
    // and is recalled the function
    for(int x = 0; x < population.size(); x++){
        Vector<Float> aggiunta = new Vector<Float>(sample);
        aggiunta.add(population.elementAt(x));
        distribuzioneBernoulli(n-1, population, aggiunta);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of a [question posted on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36410/better-way-to-create-samples)

Comment: it's similar, it changes the algorithm. I wrothe it there because someone said me that there is the right place

Answer (score 1):

You are not calculating any samples. Instead, you are creating all possible sequences out of the elements on `population` of length `n`. Consider `population = {1, 1, 2, 3}` and `n = 3`. Then you would produce:

```
1 1 1    1 1 1    2 1 1    3 1 1
1 1 1    1 1 1    2 1 1    3 1 1
1 1 2    1 1 2    2 1 2    3 1 2
1 1 3    1 1 3    2 1 3    3 1 3
1 1 1    1 1 1    2 1 1    3 1 1
1 1 1    1 1 1    2 1 1    3 1 1
1 1 2    1 1 2    2 1 2    3 1 2
1 1 3    1 1 3    2 1 3    3 1 3
1 2 1    1 2 1    2 2 1    3 2 1
1 2 1    1 2 1    2 2 1    3 2 1
1 2 2    1 2 2    2 2 2    3 2 2
1 2 3    1 2 3    2 2 3    3 2 3
1 3 1    1 3 1    2 3 1    3 3 1
1 3 1    1 3 1    2 3 1    3 3 1
1 3 2    1 3 2    2 3 2    3 3 2
1 3 3    1 3 3    2 3 3    3 3 3
```

The number of sequences is `population.sizen` (here: 4³ = 64).

A *Bernoulli sample* would return *one* of these sequences with equal probability.

If you want to return a Bernoulli sample, then the following code would be better:

```
static <T> List<T> bernoulliSample(int size, List<T> population, Random rng) {
  assert population != null;
  assert rng != null;
  List<T> sequence = new ArrayList<T>(size);
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    sequence.add(population.get(rng.nextInt(population.size())));
  }
  return sequence;
}
```

If you want to construct all possible sequences (≠ permutations), then we can pre-allocate a data structure that holds all sequences. However, it might be better to return an `Iterator` or `Iterable` object that computes the sequences lazily.

#### Eager solution

```
static <T> List<List<T>> allSequences(int size, List<T> population) {
  assert population != null;
  assert size >= 0;
  int sequenceCount = ipow(population.size(), n); // see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10517609/1521179

  List<List<T>> sequences = new ArrayList<List<T>>(sequenceCount);

  for (int i = 0; i < sequenceCount; i++) {
    sequences.add(sequenceAt(i, population));
  }

  return sequences;
}
```

Now what is `sequenceAt`? Each integer in the range `[0, sequenceCount)` can be translated into a specific sequence, much like decimal numbers can be translated into octal. The difference here is that instead of digits, we have items in `population`.

```
private static <T> List<T> sequenceAt(int size, int n, List<T> population) {
  List<T> sequence = new ArrayList<T>(size);

  for (int i : asBase(size, n, population.size())) {
    sequence.add(population.get(i));
  }

  return sequence;
}
```

Notice that we don't copy around any half-finished lists here, and we don't rely on recursion.

This method here will transform an integer into a list of digits in another base:

```
private static int[] asBase(int size, int n, int base) {
  int digits[] = new int[size];

  for (int i = size - 1, rem = n; i >= 0; i--, rem /= base) {
    digits[i] = rem % base;
  }

  return digits;
}
```

#### Lazy solution

This can reuse the helper methods from above solution.

```
class Sequences<T> implements Iterable<List<T>> {

  private final List<T> population;
  private final int     count;
  private final int     size;

  public Sequences(int size, List<T> population) {
    assert population != null;
    this.population = population;

    assert size >= 0;
    this.size = size:

    this.count = ipow(population.size(), size); // see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10517609/1521179
  }

  public Iterator<List<T>> iterator() {
    return new Iterator<List<T>>() {
      int cursor = 0;

      public boolean hasNext() {
        return cursor < count;
      }

      public List<T> next() {
        if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
        return sequenceAt(size, cursor++, population);
      }

      public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
      }

      // sequenceAt, asBase
    };
  }

  // ipow

}
```

Now we could print out all sequences like

```
for (List<Integer> sequence : new Sequences<Integer>(3, Arrays.asList(1, 1, 2, 3))) {
    for (int i : sequence) System.out.print(i + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

With both of these solutions we could skip the indirection from translating a number to a specific sequence. Instead, we could maintain an array of indices directly and update it after each sequence. Such a solution could be more efficient, as it results in fewer allocations.